# Search get request parameter in multiple columns of a csv file

Tags: python, flask

I have this flask API in which the user can do a get request with a name they input. The thing is, I want to be able to search for that name in two different columns but I am not sure how to do that, given that this does not work since flask says 'cannot index with multidimensional key':

```
data = self.data.loc[self.data[['name-english','name_greek']] == name_cap].to_dict()
```

This is the part I'm talking about:

```
class Search(Resource):
   def __init__(self):
       self.data = pd.read_csv('datacsv')

   def get(self, name):
       name_cap = name.capitalize()
       data = self.data.loc[self.data['name-english'] == name_cap].to_dict()
       # return data found in csv
       return jsonify({'message': data})
```

So I want to search in both those columns instead of just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have a problem in your pandasDataframe syntax, not in the Flask itself. You are probably getting this error from pandas:

> ValueError: cannot index with multidimensional key

According to pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

> .loc[] is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean
> array.
>
> Allowed inputs are:
>
> - A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label
>   of the index, and never as an integer position along the index).
> - A list or array of labels, e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'].
> - A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f'.
> - A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g.
>   [True, False, True].
> - An alignable boolean Series. The index of the key will be aligned
>   before masking.
> - An alignable Index. The Index of the returned selection will be the
>   input.
> - A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or
>   DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the
>   above)

In you example you are giving `self.data[['name-english','name_greek']] == name_cap` as a parameter to loc, this will return another dataframe, not an array of True and False or a boolean Series.

To filter your dataframe based on multiple columns you can use bitwise operators (& and | for example):

```
df.loc[(df["A"] == 1) | (df["B"] == 1)]
```

Or using the implemented method [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html?highlight=isin):

> Whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values.
>
> Returns: DataFrame
> DataFrame of booleans showing whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values.

Alongside with [`any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

> Return whether any element is True, potentially over an axis.
>
> Returns: Series or DataFrame
> If level is specified, then, DataFrame is returned; otherwise, Series is returned.

This way you'll have your boolean series to pass as parameter to you .loc, as the example:

```
df.loc[ df.isin([1]).any(1)]
```

Also, something that always helps me a lot dealing with dataframes is using jupyter to test somethings first, I think it's faster and you can mess around more in the dataframe to discover new ways to do what you need.